# how to find the column name of first and last negative value per each row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find the column name of first and last row with negative value and add it to the data frame as two columns as "firststatus" and "laststatus". Here is an example:

```
structure(c(NA, NA, "11", "-8.01e-14", NA, "6", NA, "-3", "-7", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, "3", "-5.0015e-8", NA, NA, NA, NA, "-4.5e+00", NA, "50.5", "51", 
        "51", "50.5", "53", "52"), .Dim = c(3L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
          c("1001", "1002", "1003"), c("50", "50.5", "51", "51.5", 
                                       "52", "52.5", "53", "firststatus", "laststatus")))
```

How can I make it? The output should be:

```
 dat$firststatus = c(50.5,51, 51)
dat$laststatus = c(50.5,53,52)
```

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AdamQuek i tried to see if something similar to max.col() works, but failed.

Comment: @AdamQuek do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```r
cbind(dat, `colnames<-`(t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  x <- grep("-", x);
  colnames(dat)[x[c(1, length(x))]]
  })), c("firststatus", "laststatus")))
#>      50   50.5 51   51.5 52   52.5 53   firststatus laststatus
#> 1001 "9"  "-8" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "50.5"      "50.5"    
#> 1002 NA   NA   "-3" NA   "3"  NA   "-4" "51"        "53"      
#> 1003 "11" "6"  "-7" NA   "-5" NA   NA   "51"        "52"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank, when I applied it to the larger data set, it gives me error: Error in dimansio (x) <-dn: length of dimension [2] equal to array content. Do you know why?

Comment: There could be several reasons. Without seeing your real data, it's difficult to tell. Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(dat)`?

Comment: yes, I have added to the edited question, for example some of the negative numbers are e.g: -5.0015e-8. here is: structure(c(NA, NA, "11", "-8.01e-14", NA, "6", NA, "-3", "-7", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, "3", "-5.0015e-8", NA, NA, NA, NA, "-4.5e+00", NA, "50.5", "51", 
        "51", "50.5", "53", "52"), .Dim = c(3L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
          c("1001", "1002", "1003"), c("50", "50.5", "51", "51.5", 
                                       "52", "52.5", "53", "firststatus", "laststatus")))